# Ошибка npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Нахожусь вроде как в нужной директории, но при запуске npm start пишет, что не в той директории. Пробовал запускать VSC от имени администратора и удалять package-lock.json[image: ошибка]

Comment: не там пишите, другую папку откройте, оно файл `package.json` найти не может

Comment: да, папку с проектом не открыл :)